# Determine the possible eigenvalue of a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator such that $$F(F (\vec{x})) = F(\vec{x}) + 2\vec{x} $$ $\forall$ $x \in V$. Determine the possible eigenvalues. Prove it.

Here is my solution. I cannot decided if it is quite right or not.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $F$ such that $F(\vec{x}) = \lambda \vec{x}$.
Note that $F^2(\vec{x}) = F \circ F(\vec{x})=F(F(\vec{x})).$ Then we have $F(\lambda \vec{x})= \lambda^2\vec{x} + 2\vec{x}$.
$\implies \vec{x}(\lambda^2 +2)=\vec{0}.$ $\vec{x} \ne \vec{0}$. 
$\implies \lambda = \pm i\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: In the equation $F(\lambda x) = \lambda^2x+2x,$ the $\lambda^2$ is wrong.

Comment: should you not get $\lambda^2 = \lambda + 2?$

Comment: I am leaning toward the right hand side ought to be $\lambda \vec{x} + 2\vec{x}$

Comment: If what you say is correct Abel, then I get $\lambda = -4$

Comment: the quadratic equation $\lambda^2 = \lambda + 2$ has roots $\lambda = 2, -1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $F$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$, so that $F(x) = \lambda x$ and $x \neq 0$.  We then have
$$
F(x) = \lambda x\\
F(F(x)) = F(\lambda x) = \lambda F(x) = \lambda(\lambda x) = \lambda^2 x
$$
So, we have
$$
F(F(x)) = F(x) - 2x \implies\\
\lambda^2 x = \lambda x - 2x \implies\\
(\lambda^2 - \lambda + 2)x = 0
$$
So, $\lambda$ must be a value satisfying $\lambda^2 - \lambda + 2 = 0$, i.e. $(\lambda - 2)(\lambda + 1) = 0$.  So, $\lambda$ must be $2$ or $-1$.